# IOS Get if a telephone number is iphone or android

Tags: ios, phone-number

I am developing an IOS App and I want to know in my AdressBook what numbers have an iPhone. I know that iOS use this function to enable or disable to communicate with Facetime to other contacts.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score -1):

Well there is no way you can get the list of iPhone users by their phone numbers. And you are talking about Facetime....I think they are maintaining the database of facetime users with their phone numbers or emails.

And so If you want to do something like this...You need to register the users of your app with  their numbers and emails and verify them as well...

UPDATE:
When calling someone using their email address, they must verify that email address for use with FaceTime and be signed in to their Apple ID account.

Please refer this [article](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4319)

Comment: This is not what I mean.how iphone knows what device has a facetime or not? I want something similar